# tools.jar does not come with jdk installation

Tags: java

I was trying to download and install new jdk for brushing up my java, but it seems the jdk installation doesn't have the `tools.jar` file in the lib directory. Am I missing something?
I tried installing it from this link https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows
I tried both exe and msi but none seems to work and when I tried running the code I get `Error:Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 17 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17)`

I tried to search for this issue, but most question where asked by people who installed `jre` instead, or who didn't set the `set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"`

```
>java --version
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: You'll need to go back to Java 8, because they removed it in Java 9, see [Removed rt.jar and tools.jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1)

Comment: @Scratte Oh! So how do you run programs using jdk-17??!!! As I said, I was just trying to brush up my java after more than 1/2 a decade by playing around. I just tried to run a simple command line `hello world` program in intelliJ to check if the installation is working and it threw that error. Since I don't have any particular requirements, is there a new way to setup and run a java code?

Comment: You don't need tools.jar to run a Java program. I don't know about IntelliJ. It is a recent version? If it was me, I'd just search for any IntelliJ tutorial on how to get started. If you have an old version of IntelliJ, I believe you can still [download Java 8 from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8).

Comment: @Scratte The IntelliJ version is July 2020, so it is kinda new, but I am downloading the latest right now. But I saw a bunch of tutorials and tried to follow them, it was basically what I was doing, but I tried to redo it again. But I found one peculiar thing. When I selected the `Project SDK` to `14.0.1` which I had previously on my system, instead of `17` the code ran without any errors and gave the `hello world` output. So I don't know why its giving an error for `17`.  Are there any BIG differences in `14.0.1` vs `17` ?? If not, I guess I'll have to make do with `14.0.1`

Comment: Java 17 came on September 14, 2021, so I suspect your IntelliJ just gets confused about it. You can try Java 16 which is the latest version on Long Term Support. But that came on March 16, 2021, so that may get your IDE similarly confused. If Java 14 works, then all's well :)

Comment: @Scratte K. Thanks a lot. Yeah, now that you mention it, since it came after the version of IntelliJ, that could infact be the issue.

Comment: You should upgrade your IntelliJ to a 2021 version

Comment: I'm not sure which changes they made which would impact an IDE. As far as I understand those changes are mostly interesting for IDE developers and getting a "quick" overview is unlikely. For more apparent changes, I usually use [The wikipedia Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) which links to each JEP (JDK Enhancement Proposal) separately. Looking at it, it seems I was mistaken about the latest Long Term Supported version, which is now 17.

Comment: @Scratte Yes 17 is the LTS version. So I did install IntelliJ 2021.2.2 which is the latest version. And it did ran without error. But before I got this msg `You must accept the terms of legal notice of the beta Java specification to enable support for "17 - Sealed types, always-strict floating-point semantics".  The implementation of an early-draft specification developed under the Java Community Process (JCP) is made available for testing and evaluation purposes only and is not compatible with any specification of the JCP.` and had to agree. I don't know what `"experimental"` with LTS but OK

Comment: @Scratte Anyways, Thanks for all your help. If you would like to post `ANSWER` then I will accept it. Otherwise I will accept rzwitserloot's `ANS` to close this question. Thanks again.

Comment: Only Questions that should never get Answers are "closed" on Stack Overflow. There's no requirement that you accept an Answer. It's voluntary by design, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I'm not sure I can add anything to a new Answer that's not already covered by the other Answer though, so I'm reluctant to post one at this point. Since Java 9, I've never actually "installed" Java. I download the .zip version and unpack it into a folder.

Answer (score 8):

`tools.jar` contains, primarily, `javac` (the compiler).

The transition from JDK8 to JDK9 broke a ton of java stuff. Including removing this jar. It's now in a module. Whatever software is looking for tools.jar will not be compatible with this new model. Oracle hides behind the idea that none of this was specced, and in fairness to Oracle/OpenJDK, it wasn't. In other words, relying on 'tools.jar' never was actually supported, but then again, the things that 'rely' on this wanted to compile java code. There is no alternative short of shipping the compiler with your app, which has license issues.

At any rate, the solution is therefore simple: Either upgrade whatever software is throwing this error at you, or if you already did / you cant, downgrade to JDK8.

Note that you can install multiple JDKs on a single system, and you can e.g. run intellij on JDK8 and then write java code inside it targeted at jDK17, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was just wrote my reply to @Scratte before your comment. As I said, when I `create new project` and choose the `Project SDK` to `14.0.1` it doesn't throw any errors and compiles and outputs `hello world`, but if I choose `17` it throw the `tools.jar` error. Why is that happening? And are there any major changes between `14.0.1` and `17`, cos if not, I guess I'll have to make do with using `14.0.1`.

Comment: No major changes. Your intellij is clearly not (yet) compatible with JDK17, and is apparently mis-identifying it as JDK7 or 8.

Answer (score 2):

just download tools.jar file from link:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtools180jar.htm
then add tools.jar file into jdk file lib folder.It will solve error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).